# Achieve popup textbox effect

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a textbox "popup" when I start to type something in my window, and when the textbox is empty have it collapsed.

Here's my current xaml:

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="2,0,3,2" x:Name="PopupSearchBox"
         Visibility="{Binding SearchFilter.Length,Converter={StaticResource _BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
         Text="{Binding SearchFilter,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Which seems to be working, but how can I have it receive input when it's collapsed so it can process it and become visible?

Comment: What about using the Window's `KeyDown` or `PreviewKeyDown` event?